Stream php-fpm and httpd logs from ECS to different Cloudwatch logs
Would it be possible to do an ECS container that has httpd and php-fpm running side-by-side, managed by supervisord all inside a single image, then have cloudwatch logs for:

supervisord logs
php-fpm error log
php-fpm access log
httpd error log
httpd access log

Or do I need to separate them into different containers and/or images?

ECS containers feed stdout to CloudWatch. You would need to setup fluentd or logstash/beats to feed other logs (files, syslog, etc.) to separate CloudWatch logs.
